# Why is SQL Server Service Broker a broker and not a bus?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am aware of the difference between a service broker (centralized) and service bus (decentralized). Is it not that multiple SQL Servers communicating using their Service Broker are considered a decentralized service bus? Why not?

Many thx.

Comment: Is there a reason for the down voting? How can I improve my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work performed by [Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver16) is centralized though. It is a central point of services that manage messages and handle queuing, between applications and databases:

> SQL Server Service Broker provide native support for messaging and queuing in the SQL Server Database Engine and Azure SQL Managed Instance. Developers can easily create sophisticated applications that use the Database Engine components to communicate between disparate databases, and build distributed and reliable applications.
>
> Use Service Broker components to implement native in-database asynchronous message processing functionalities. Application developers who use Service Broker can distribute data workloads across several databases without programming complex communication and messaging internals. Service Broker reduces development and test work because Service Broker handles the communication paths in the context of a conversation.

Comment: I guess if I consider one SQL Server to represent one service, then it will be a bus.